# Using inline style with jQuery appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a user script in Greasemonkey and I am currently adding elements to a text box. I have tried unsuccessfully to use inline CSS within the created element like so

**CSS**

```
.append($("<p style="color:blue">"))
```

Is this even possible to do with jQuery? I couldn't find any examples of this searching around and I'm still really new to coding, so I apologize if this has been answered before.

Comment: You can use the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) property

Comment: the question and code are not clear

Comment: I'm sorry, on mobile right now and the code isn't getting saved correctly when I submit. Trying to fix it now

Comment: What kind of textbox?

Comment: It's a basic form with inputs contained in a div

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to append a inline-styled `<p>` tag to a `<div>` tag you have to use:

```
var parentNode = $('div');
var childNode = $('<p>'); 
childNode.css('color', 'blue'); 
parentNode.append(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last post asking really well to question but your first approach works also (you just forget the '/' at the end).

Supposing you want just adding a simple "p" empty element, you can just do this (with Jquery):

```
$(element).append('<p style="color:red" />')
```

or if you want to add a p no empty element do this :

```
$(element).append('<p style="color:red" > My text </p>')
```

It's the shortest way to do that but the last post show a more cleaning technic to do that.

Comment: Thank you, and actually I forgot part of my original code, it should have a </p> in there as well. Does that change anything? Also is my use of double quotes around the element make a difference?

Comment: Yes it make a big difference, indeed by putting "" in middle of your string you break your string. You can see easily on your post, the color of "color:blue" isn't same of the rest of your string. Look **how to concat string in javascript** and you will understand that.

Comment: `"my text " some text " end of text"` --> send error : break string              `"my text \" some text \" end of text"` --> good                                           `"my text 'some text' end of text"` --> good

Comment: Thank you so much,! That makes sense and explains a lot.